# flutter form validation error message extends textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

When a validation error occurs on the form, `CustomTextField` resizes itself as the following.

[image]

However, I would like the error message to be displayed outside of `CustomTextField`. To accomplish that, I made the following design.
[image: validation error outside of CustomTextField]

There is one flaw in this design which is that, since I am not returning any text inside the `validator` (always returns null) in `CustomTextField`. This condition `_formKey.currentState!.validate()`  is always evaluated as `true`. That means, whether the provided `email` or `password` is valid, the API call will be made. The following if-statement is always executed.

```
handleLogin() {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
//always executed.
      BlocProvider.of<LoginCubit>(context).loginUser(LoginRequest(
          password: _passwordController.text,
          email: _emailController.text.trim()));
    }
  }
```

`CustomTextField` call

```
    CustomTextField(
                              validateFunc: Validate.validateEmail,
                              controller: _emailController,
                              maxLength: 100,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              labelText: "Email",
                              hintText: 'kimsebosyapmasin@gmail.com',
                            ),
```

`custom_text_field.dart`. The summary of the problem is commented on in the following code inside of `validator`.

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String labelText;
  final int maxLines;
  final int maxLength;
  final Function? validateFunc;

  const CustomTextField(
      {super.key,
      required this.hintText,
      this.validateFunc,
      required this.controller,
      required this.labelText,
      required this.maxLines,
      required this.maxLength});

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  String? errorMessage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Text(
            widget.labelText,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .titleMedium
                ?.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary),
          ),
        ),
        Material(
          elevation: 10,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          child: TextFormField(

            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
            maxLines: widget.maxLines,
            inputFormatters: [
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(widget.maxLength),
            ],
            controller: widget.controller,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
              focusColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
              hintText: widget.hintText,
              hintStyle: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodySmall
                  ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              if (widget.validateFunc != null) {
                setState(() {
                  errorMessage = widget.validateFunc!(value);  
/* I shouldn't return any text if not valid 
because it will extend the customtextfield.
 However, this time, _formKey.currentState!.validate() is always true.
*/
                });
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
        ),
        TextValidationError(errorMessage: errorMessage)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`validateFunc` for email.

```
static validateEmail(email) {
    bool emailValid = RegExp(r'^.+@[a-zA-Z]+\.{1}[a-zA-Z]+(\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)$')
        .hasMatch(email);

    if (!emailValid) {
      return ValidationConst.emailError;
    }
  }
```

What do you suggest to solve this problem? Actually, I would like to ask that is my logic ok? If it's what should I do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What i suggest
Create a custom class with column->Text Input field with custom design like rounded white background -> Text with red color it will behave as error and then use this component to re-render email and password.

Comment: As far as  I understand, your are reffering to my `TextValidationError` , where I display the form errors, right? you can see it inside  the `custom_text_field.dart`